# hydraulic brakes not working very fast

Tags: brakes, hydraulic-disc-brake, brake-pads

Ok, so I just got new hydraulic brakes, I have not had any like these and they were fitted by professionals and they had replaced the pads as I had contaminated the old ones. After getting these fitted they aren't very sharp at all and can take up to 5 seconds to respond and make my back tyre lock up. So I was just wondering if anyone knows how I could make them better.

Comment: I am certain this is a duplicate, but I can't see one. [Bedding in](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2193/why-how-should-i-bed-in-disc-brake-pads?s=1|2.7497) new pads [is half the answer](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/17308/grinding-sound-on-new-disc-brakes), but it could also be [contamination](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32671/moaning-disc-brakes) or they might just be badly assembled or installed.

Comment: most likely pads need bedding in. Could be pad type - switching to organics will give better bite. Brakes could also need bleeding.

Comment: Don't lock up your brakes on purpose - the art in fast braking is to be just below the lockup point, combined with moving your weight backwards.  Else flatspots on tyre/tire.   Otherwise, your brakes should be much better.  Do they take 5 seconds to have a noticeable braking effect, or do they take 5 seconds to close the pistons-> pads into the rotor ?   Is it the same lag for both front and rear ?

Comment: @Criggie It takes 5 seconds to notice it, but it does come on quick

Comment: What was contaminating the brakes the first time?  Seems that they are still contaminated or it has happened again.  Even if they aren't bedded in, they will work sooner than 5 seconds.  I am guessing they are glazed and that's why you have to get them hot before they will work (5 seconds of rubbing)

Comment: They aren't these brakes by chance are they?  http://forums.mtbr.com/brake-time/shimano-br-m485-disc-brakes-recall-sorts-442379.html

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping up all the comments, it appears that your brake mechanism applies okay, but doesn't achieve enough braking performance to slow you quickly.

The likely cause is that you've never bedded in the brake pads.  Apply the links in @Móż comment to bed your brakes in properly.  If they're too naffed you might need new pads to start the bedding in process again.